# Nginx and HHVM always return a 404

Tags: php, nginx, hhvm

I know this is not an uncommon problem, but somehow I don’t seem to be able to find a direct answer. Is somebody able to answer this as straight forward as possible?

*My NGINX (deliver static files) and HHVM (`hhvm index.php` from console) are working just fine, but I can't access a .php through NGINX without getting a 404*

Situation:
HHVM 3.5.0
Nginx 1.7.9

I have this in my /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        root   /var/www;
        index  index.php index.html index.htm;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    include hhvm.conf;
}
```

In HHVM.conf

```
location ~ \.(hh|php)$ {
    fastcgi_keep_conn on;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the below HHVM conf with yours:

```
location ~ \.(hh|php)$ {
    fastcgi_keep_conn on;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}
```

**Problem**

I see a space between `$document_root` and `$fastcgi_script_name`.

**Update**
Solved by changing `$document_root` with `/var/www`

Comment: Did you try replacing `$document_root` with the absolute path?

Comment: you mean /var/www in this context?

Comment: Yes, provide `/var/www` and try

Comment: There's a problem with this solution: doing this changes adds absolute path to redirect URL.

Answer (score 2):

The `root` directive is defined inside `location`, this is why it is not accessible inside hhvm.conf via the variable `$document_root`.

It should be moved directly to the level of `server`:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    root   /var/www;

    location / {
        index  index.php index.html index.htm;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    include hhvm.conf;
}
```

Then, no modification is needed in your `hhvm.conf`, although you may [do some cleanup there too](http://blog.afa.moe/201411/nginx-fastcgi-hhvm-pitfalls/).